# Dataset retrieving data from another dataset

Tags: database, delphi, ado, delphi-2007

I work with an application that it switching from filebased datastorage to database based. It has a very large amount of code that is written specifically towards the filebased system. To make the switch I am implementing functionality that will work as the old system, the plan is then making more optimal use of the database in new code.

One problem is that the filebased system often was reading single records, and read them repeatedly for reports. This have become alot of queries to the database, which is slow.

The idea I have been trying to flesh out is using two datasets. One dataset to retrieve an entire table, and another dataset to query against the first, thereby decreasing communication overhead with the database server.

I've tried to look at the `DataSource` property of `TADODataSet` but the dataset still seems to require a connection, and it asks the database directly if `Connection` is assigned.

The reason I would prefer to get the result in another dataset, rather than navigating the first one, is that there is already implemented a good amount of logic for emulating the old system. This logic is based on having a dataset containing only the results as queried with the old interface.

The functionality only have to support reading data, not writing it back.

**How can I use one dataset to supply values for another dataset to select from?**

I am using Delphi 2007 and MSSQL.

Comment: The purpose of the DataSource property of TADODataSet is to allow Data Aware controls to connect to a TDataSet without knowing what kind of TDataSet descendant is used. To link dataset you would use the MasterSource and MasterFields properties. But even with a 1-1 between master and detail that won't allow you to use a "select from TDataSet1" as the selection for your other dataset.

Comment: @Marjan I though the DataSource property of TADODataSet was to allow TADODataSet to be that Data Aware component. The VCL reference says "Represents the data source of another dataset that supplies values to the dataset."

Comment: you are right. I responded purely on the basis of "DataSource" as a name. The DataSource of a data aware control is what connects it to its dataset. But the DataSource of a dataset is indeed a different beast altogether. I looked at TClientDataSet and apparently that is the only dataset with a MasterSource. Other TDataSet descendants indeed have a DataSource and that seems to be what MasterSource is for a TClientDataSet, as TADODataSet/TSQLDataSet do not have a MasterSource but do have a MasterFields property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ClientDataSet/DataSetProvider pair to fetch data from an existing DataSet.  You can use filters on the source dataset, filters on the ClientDataSet and provider events to trim the dataset only to the interesting records.

I've used this technique with success in a couple of migrating projects and to mitigate similar situation where a old SQL Server 7 database was queried thousands of times to retrieve individual records with painful performance costs.  Querying it only one time and then fetching individual records to the client dataset was, at the time, not only an elegant solution but a great performance boost to that particular application: The most great example was an 8 hour process reduced to 15 minutes... poor users loved me that time.

A ClientDataSet is just a TDataSet you can seamlessly integrate into existing code and UI.